# Reversal Badge error

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Maybe a little bug, even though I think it worth to report.

In [Badges section](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges) you see that Reversal Badge has 1 awarded, like bellow.

[image]

But when you click on it, there isn't any awarded. See below:

[image]

Comment: David Kessner got that badge a few months ago, so it's probably related to his account deletion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the job that synced these counts routinely, specifically it wouldn't fix the "now 0" case, a join vs. a left join going on.  This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: And what about the [other bug](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3162/error-for-profile-less-info) I have reported?